# how to create new data for ar_pose

Tags: ar-pose

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. I would like to ask if the bagfiles in open for public. Cause the access deny when i tried to download the files.
2. I am now trying to calibrate my camera (Logitech Carl Zeiss Tessar) under `calib_camera2` from artoolkit, it shows the following error

   ```
    Using supplied video config string [-width=640 -height=480].
   ```

   ioctl failed

   init(): Unable to open connection to camera.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/114366/how-to-create-new-data-for-ar_pose/) by [chao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9591/chao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2014-01-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See https://github.com/LucidOne/ar_tools/pull/4 for a way to fix the access denied problem (the repository has moved)

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`2.` Why not use  the standard ROS camera calibration?
http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2014-01-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9591/chao/) on 2014-01-02**:
cos i am prompted to enter "camera parameter filename(Data/camera_para.dat)" when i am running ./mk_patt under the artoolkit. If i ignore the prompt and continue, it gave me an error message "Using supplied video config string [-width=640 -height=480].   ioctl failed   setupCamera(): Unable to open connection to camera.   main(): Unable to set up AR camera."

**Comment by [chao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9591/chao/) on 2014-01-02**:
so i suppose that i will need the calibration file in dat format? and do you know why i am getting that error (unable to open connection to camera)?

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2014-01-02**:
You are able to view images from the camera using the driver?
I just used the marker in  ~/ros/stacks/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_vision/artoolkit/build/artoolkit-svn/patterns/pattHiro.pdf

**Comment by [chao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9591/chao/) on 2014-01-02**:
no, the process stops after the error. i am using pattHiro as well. but when i launch the ar_pose_single.launch as suggested in the tutorial, it can't detect anything. so, i am not sure if the training data "data/4x4/4x4_1.patt" used in default is the correct data or not?

**Comment by [chao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9591/chao/) on 2014-01-02**:
btw, it shows **unable to set control: Input/output error ** ERROR: could not set some settings. ** unable to set control ** when i am launch ar_pose_single.launch. will it affect the process with improper settings maybe?

**Comment by [chao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9591/chao/) on 2014-01-02**:
i managed to solve the problem by using 4x4_384_1.gif in ar_pose/data/4x4 folder with the default ar_pose_single.launch that using 4x4_1.patt. and indeed the "unable to set control: Input/output error" will affect the result. when i am launching it thru another driver, which don't give me the same error, is able to track the marker easier, and the image provided by this is exposed more (more pale in general)